# How to optimize rejection sampling

Tags: c++, optimization, dictionary, sample, random

I have an std::map mymap that I am trying to sample based on the values for each key. I have set up an algorithm based on rejection sampling that seems to be working, however it is extremely slow (this algorithm gets called thousands of times in my program).

So I am wondering if this would be the best approach or if there is something quicker/more efficient that I could be doing instead.

Here is what I have so far below:

```
std::map<int, float> mymap; //My map that I am sampling

//These three floats are precomputed
int minKey;  //Min key in the map.  
int maxKey;  //Max key in the map.  
float maxValue; //Max value in the map.  

float x1, x2; //Two random variables;
int key;
float value;
do 
{
    x1 = (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    x2 = maxValue * (float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    key = minKey*(1.0-x1) + maxKey*x1; //Linearly interpolate random value to get key;
    value = mymap[key]; //Get value;
} while(x2 > value) 


return std::pair<int, float)(key, value);
```

^So what I am doing above is uniformly randomly selecting a key. Then creating another random variable and comparing it against that key's value. If it is larger, repeat the process. This way, keys with higher values get sampled more often than keys with lower values. However, the do-while loop can loop many times before finding an acceptable key-value pair to sample and this is causing quite the bottleneck in my application

**EDIT**

Also, is it necessary for me to do any adjusting to my samples since they are biased here? I know that in monte carlo integration, you have to divide the value of the sample by the PDF of that sample...but I'm not sure if that would apply here. If it does apply, how would I find the PDF?

Comment: I don't know how you can call this a uniform sample when you're clearly biasing it.

Comment: ^That was a typo -- I meant that I am uniformly sampling keys as part of the algorithm in order to do the rejection sampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rejection sampling is primarily useful for continuous distributions. What you need is to [sample a discrete distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling#Finite_discrete_distributions). Fortunately, this is part of STL in C++11. So, adapted from the sample of [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

template <typename T>
class sampler
{
    std::vector<T> keys;
    std::discrete_distribution<T> distr;

public:
    sampler(const std::vector<T>& keys, const std::vector<float>& prob) :
        keys(keys), distr(prob.begin(), prob.end()) { }

    T operator()()
    {
        static std::random_device rd;
        static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        return keys[distr(gen)];
    }
};

int main()
{
    using T = int;
    sampler<T> samp({19, 54, 192, 732}, {.1, .2, .4, .3});
    std::map<T, size_t> hist;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < 10000; ++n)
        ++hist[samp()];

    for (auto i: hist)
    {
        std::cout << i.first << " generated " <<
        i.second << " times" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
19 generated 1010 times
54 generated 2028 times
192 generated 3957 times
732 generated 3005 times
```

Vectors `keys` and `prob` contain separately the keys and values (probabilities) of your map. This is because `std::discrete_distribution` takes into account only the probabilities.

Note that `operator()` cannot be `const` because `std::discrete_distribution` changes state (naturally) at every sample.

Also note that even you implement sampling yourself using the cumulative distribution and binary search (whereby sampling is logarithmic-time in the size of your domain), there are more efficient (constant-time) sampling methods like the [alias method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method). I am not sure what method is used by 
`std::discrete_distribution`, however.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea C++ 11 included this kind of functionality. This is pretty cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bias your sample linearly in proportion to the values, it's easy to do.

Start by calculating the sum of all the values.

Now generate a single random floating-point value between 0 and the sum.

Iterate through the map, summing the values as you go. When the sum is greater than the random value calculated earlier, you've found your sample.

If you'll be doing this repeatedly on an unchanging map, you can create a vector of sums and do a binary search for the random value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A few questions though:



1) Would iterating over the map each time to get a sample actually be quicker than a do-while loop on average? Also the values in the map aren't stored in any particular order. Would that affect how the method you've described performs?

2) Do I need to weight the samples by dividing them by the PDF as per Monte Carlo integration? Or is the weighting already intrinsically taken care of? What I am currently doing is counting up the total amount of times a particular key-value pair is sampled and dividing the value by that amount

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using a second `map` (or `set`) with the not-known-bad keys (you put all the keys there, and once you reject a key because it's larger than the initial random variable, you delete it from the map -- and you search for the key in the not-known-bad set, not in the entire map...